# C - Add a string into an array x and remove it from an array y

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I created a gaming platform and i wanna let trade some games.

So I managed to elaborate a code where a user can sell his games to a marketplace and another user could buy it whenever he wants, if he has credit. In order to do it, I need to add the sold game to the buyer's library and remove it from the seller's library, but there's something I'm missing.

The code I wrote is more or less:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    char username [15];
    char email [25];
    char surname [20];
    char name [20];
    char sex;
    int hours;
    int level;
    float credit;
    char* library[20];
} User;

typedef struct {
    char id_code [7];
    char name [35];
    char developer [30];
    char category [15];
    float price;
    int pegi;
    char seller [15];
} Game;

...

int main() {
    int max=1, z=0, u=0;
    User signed_up [max];
    Game database [20], marketplace [20];
...
system("pause");
return 0;
}

...

void buy_game (int max, int *pz, int *pu, User signed_up[], Game database[], Game marketplace[]) {
    int i=0, j=0, h=0, y=0, x=0, a=0, b=0, w=0, v=0, c=0;
    bool game_found=false, user_found=false, not_owned_game=false;
    char input_game [35], input_user[15];

    v=*pz;
    w=*pu;

    ...

    printf("\n%*sInserisci username dell'utente con cui acquistare il gioco: ", 26, "");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", input_user);
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<max-1;i++) {
        if (strcmp(input_user, signed_up[i].username)==0) {
            user_found=true;

            printf("%*sInserisci nome del gioco da acquistare: ", 26, "");
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(input_game, sizeof (input_game), stdin);
            input_game[strlen(input_game)-1]='\0';
            printf("\n");

            for (j=0;j<w;j++) {
                if (strcmp(input_game, marketplace[j].name)==0) {
                    game_found=true;

                    for (h=0;h<max-1;h++) {
                        if (strcmp(signed_up[h].username, marketplace[j].seller)==0) {
                            for (y=0;y<v;y++) {
                                if (strcmp(marketplace[j].name, signed_up[h].library[y])==0) {
                                    for (a=0;a<v;a++) {
                                        if (strcmp(marketplace[j].name, signed_up[i].library[a])!=0) {
                                            not_owned_game=true;

                                            if (marketplace[j].price<=signed_up[i].credit) {

                                            printf("\n%*sOperazione avvenuta con successo!\n", 26, "");
                                            signed_up[i].credit=signed_up[i].credit-marketplace[j].price;
                                            printf("\n%*sIl credito attuale dell'utente %s %c: EUR %.2f\n", 26, "", signed_up[i].username, 138, signed_up[i].credit);
                                            signed_up[h].credit=signed_up[h].credit+marketplace[j].price;
                                            printf("\n%*sIl credito attuale dell'utente %s %c: EUR %.2f\n\n\n", 26, "", signed_up[h].username, 138, signed_up[h].credit);

                                            signed_up[i].library[y]=marketplace[j].name;
                                            //add game to buyer's library

                                            do {
                                                signed_up[h].library[y]=signed_up[h].library[y+1];
                                                y+=1;
                                            } while (y<v-1);
                                            signed_up[h].library[v-1]="";
                                            //remove game from seller's library

                                            do {
                                                marketplace[j]=marketplace[j+1];
                                                j+=1;
                                            } while (j<w-1);
                                            *pu-=1;
                                            //remove game from marketplace
                                            } else {
                                                printf("%*sCredito acquirente insufficiente! Si prega di ricaricare il conto.\n\n", 26, "");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } if (not_owned_game==false) {
                                        printf("%*sGioco inserito gi%c presente nella libreria dell'utente!\n\n\n", 26, "", 133);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } if (game_found==false) {
                printf("%*sGioco inserito non presente nel marketplace!\n\n\n", 26, "");
            }
        }
    } if (user_found==false) {
        printf("\n%*sUsername inserito non presente nel database!\n\n\n", 26, "");
    }
}
```

The issue I have is the program has a weird behaviour when I check users' libraries cause it doesn't memorize properly both buyer and seller's libraries; in fact the program refuses to show any game in their libraries.

Comment: You need to ask an explicit question

Comment: "there's something I'm missing". What are you missing? You need to explain clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Please use more meaningful variable names than `h`, `v`, `pz`, `pu`, etc. The logic is very difficult to understand.

Comment: Sorry, I just specified the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Arrays have fixed size, so you can't remove entries.  You can overwrite, and you can shift things around, either of which might result in a particular value no longer existing in the array.

So think about what you want your fixed-size array to look like when it *logically* contains one fewer item, because you can't actually shrink it.  Then think about what changes need to be made to mutate the array to the desired state, and finally write the code.